# Testing traversal of binary search tree (BST)

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, googletest

What is a good way to test the in-order traversal of a binary search tree with Google Test?  I can test it manually by printing out the values of the nodes and verifying that the list is sorted visually. Is there a way to validate this automatically using Google Test?  I was thinking of adding a static string to the node class and appending to the string for every node visited.  The problem with this is that there could be multiple trees which should each have their own in-order list but there can only be one static string.

Once I get it working with the in-order traversal the solution should be extensible to pre-order and post-order traversals.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the previous entry and when you're no longer on the first entry.

Assert that you're still on the first entry or the current entry is >= the previous entry.

Comment: This will work but there's no way to expose this result to Google Test.  It also adds test code to my implementation that will always run even when it's not being called by Google Test.

Comment: Add a traversal routine taking a lambda, functor, or function + state as its argument. Use that for both test purposes and to implement your print function. `bool inorder(Node* node, std::function<bool(Node*)> fn) { return node ? inorder(node->left) && fn(node) && inorder(node->right) : true; }`

Comment: `Node *prev(); ASSERT_TRUE(inorder(root, [&prev](Node* node){ if (prev && node->val < prev->val) { return false; } else { prev = node; return true; } }));`